# Store value in array without overwrite the previous guessed letter

Tags: javascript

Im creating an hangman-game but when I run the program, the correct guesses overwrites themselves...
My code for the function guess a letter is shown here...how do I store the guessed letters in the array "letterBoxes" without overwrite the previous value?

```
// Globala variabler
var wordList;  
var selectedWord;  på
var letterBoxes; 
var hangmanImg; 
var hangmanImgNr; 
var msgElem;  

function init() {
var i;
var startGameBtn;
var letterButtons;
wordList = 


["BLOMMA","LASTBIL","SOPTUNNA","KÖKSBORD","RADIOAPPARAT","VINTER","SOMMAR","DATORMUS","LEJON","ELEFANTÖRA","JULTOMTE",
            "SKOGSHYDDA","BILNUMMER","BLYERTSPENNA","SUDDGUMMI","KLÄDSKÅP","VEDSPIS","LJUSSTAKE","SKRIVBORD","ELDGAFFEL","STEKPANNA",
            "KASTRULL","KAFFEBRYGGARE","TALLRIK","SOFFBORD","TRASMATTA","FLYGPLAN","FLYGPLATS","TANGENTBORD"];

hangmanImg = document.getElementById("hangman");
msgElem = document.getElementById("message");
startGameBtn = document.getElementById("startGameBtn");
document.getElementById("startGameBtn").onclick = startGame; 
letterButtons =    
document.getElementById("letterButtons").getElementsByTagName("button");
for (i = 0; i < letterButtons.length; i++) letterButtons[i].onclick = 
guessLetter;//anrop av funktionen guessLetter

} // End init
window.onload = init; // Se till att init aktiveras då sidan är inladdad


function startGame() {

randomWord(selectedWord); //ok
showLetterBoxes(letterBoxes);
hangmanImg = "pics/h1.png"; //byt till h0.png när koden är klar
document.getElementById("hangman").src = hangmanImg;
hangmanImgNr = 0; //ok!
}
funktion skapa slumpat ord OK
function randomWord() {
var wordIndex;
wordIndex = parseInt(Math.random() * 29); 
selectedWord = wordList[wordIndex];
alert(selectedWord); 
}

function showLetterBoxes() {
var i;
var newCode;

newCode = "";
for (i = 0; i < selectedWord.length; i++) {
    newCode += "<span>&nbsp;</span>"; 
}

document.getElementById("letterBoxes").innerHTML = newCode;

document.getElementById("letterButtons").getElementsByTagName("value").innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: add the full code

Answer (score 1):

letterBoxes is an array.

You do not use + with it, you use push function.

```
letterBoxes.push("<span>" + letter + "</span >");
```

and

```
letterBoxes.push("<span>*</span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your variable `letterBoxes` outside the function else it gets overwritten every time you run the code. Alsoe you declared it as `letterBoxes = []` indicating it's an array but you use as a string in the code.

Try this:

```
letterBoxes = '';

function guessLetter()
{
var letter;
var i;

var letterFound;//flagga
var correctLettersCount;//korrekta bokstäver
correctLettersCount; //sätt antal rätt bokstäver till 0

letter = this.value;
for (i = 0; i < selectedWord.length; i++) {


    if (selectedWord.charAt(i) == letter) {
        letterBoxes += "<span>" + letter + "</span >";

        } 
    else{
        letterBoxes += "<span>*</span>";
    }


   }
   document.getElementById("letterBoxes").innerHTML = letterBoxes; 
}
```

Comment: Have you removed the line letterBoxes = []; from your code?

Comment: yes, and changed letterBoxes.push("<span>" + letter + "</span >");

Comment: No don't use letterBoxes.push. Have it like you had it before like in my example. Either you treat you variable lettterBox as an string an concatenate it with letterBoxes += or you change it to an array but then you also need to handle how you print it.... which we don't know anythhing about as we havent seen that code of yours.

Comment: So keep your line letterBoxes += "<span>" + letter + "</span >";

Comment: okay, now it is printed but now it is added a new row for every new guess

Comment: letterBoxes = "";
function guessLetter() {
    
    var letter;
    var i;
    var letterFound;
    var correctLettersCount;
    correctLettersCount;
    letter = this.value;
    for (i = 0; i < selectedWord.length; i++) {
        if (selectedWord.charAt(i) == letter) {
            letterBoxes += "<span>" + letter + "</span >";
         document.getElementById("letterBoxes").innerHTML = letterBoxes; 
   
            } 
  else{
   letterBoxes += "<span>*</span>";
   document.getElementById("letterBoxes").innerHTML = letterBoxes; 
        
       }
          
    }

Comment: Where did you want it to be placed? You can use css to place it side by side. Please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Im not allowed to change the css or html. let say the word is "javascript", if I guess a j, then j_ _ _  _ _ _ _ _ _ , then next guess, let say t: the updated word would be: j _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ t

Comment: are you using document.getElementById("letterBoxes").innerHTML = letterBoxes in both if and else ? Place it just once...after  the if else is over

Comment: You need new logics to place it on correct place then. Add a new question for that.